# Most important uses of web service

Tags: java, web-services, webservice-client

Web services are used to share the services provided by an application, to outside world. This is my basic understanding of web services.

Suppose my application is to expose some specific behaviors and I have written the code for it and exposed the methods. The ones who want to use it can take the link to the wsdl, generate stub and call the methods.

What is the use of doing all this, when I can myself expose the methods, generate a jar and bundle everything in it and share the server address,jar.

How differently is web services important, when compared to a case explained above. Am asking such a general question due to unsuccessful search in many websites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd generate a client jar, whoever wants to use that would have to deal with Java. If you expose a Web Service instead, the user can use whatever technology he/she wants to use (e.g. Python, Ruby, .net, C, C++ etc. etc.). That would be a huge advantage.

Answer (score 1):

What you are suggesting is quite close to [RESTful](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-137171.html) webservices. Unlike SOAP webservices, RESTful webservices do not require any WSDL files. All that you need to do is to issue a request to a particular URL.

As you explained correctly (in my opinion) SOAP webservices involve some more work which needs to be done, thus making them more complex, if you will, to integrate with other systems. This is not the case with RESTful webservices.

EDIT: You can check out a tutorial [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/REST/article.html). I have tried it myself a while back and it is enough to get you started.

Comment: Sorry am not aware of RESTful. From your comments, I understand that I should immediately look into RESTful web services. Thank you.

Comment: @Ajj: I have modified my answer and included a link to a tutorial that you might consider looking into. REST webservices should allow you to expose your services just by providing third parties with a URL, you do not need to provide them with any `JAR` files or what so ever. This is better since 3rd parties will not need to care about your implementation details, such as what language was used ;).

Answer (score 1):

Web service use a series of standards(SOAP, WSDL...) to make different kinds of system work together, certainly you can generate client jar as you like, but that requires your service consumer to learn how to play with it, so it's not a generic solution.

Comment: True but if I can simply provide the jar and the server URL, they can easily use the jar execute it. In the end, they are generating the client stub and creating a jar out of it to use the services exposed, right ?

Comment: If your service consumer use C# or other languages, I guess you will choose webservice standard.